# How to allow only one special character multiple times in a REGEX expression

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

I am trying to create a REGEX expression that will only allow alphanumeric characters and one special character that can be used multiple times. The special characters that can be included are `()-_,.$`. For example:
abc_def is valid
abc-def is valid
abc--def is valid
abc_-def is not valid

I tried to figure it out and came up with this: `[a-zA-Z0-9]*[\\-_().,\\$]?[a-zA-Z0-9]*` but that only allows the special character to appear once (so abc--def wouldn't be valid like I want it to). But if I change the `?` to a `*` then multiple different special characters can be included in the string (so abc-_def would be valid but I don't want it to be). I tried some other stuff like: `[[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]*[a-zA-Z0-9_]*...]` for example (my idea was that this would read as (`alphanumeric && '-') || (alphanumeric && '_') || ...`) but I can't find anything that will work.

It is also worth noting that something like: abc-def-ghi-jkl-mno should be valid, so anything of the form `[alphanumeric][specialcharacters][alphanumeric]` won't work. Additionally, the string can start and end with the special character.

Is it possible to create a REGEX expression that will work the way I want it to? Or am I stuck writing my own function? Thanks :)

P.S. I'm using this in a Validators.pattern() for form control in angular 9 in case that makes a difference

Comment: https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences

Comment: is something like `abc-def_ghi` valid?

Comment: @mjrezaee No, There can only be one unique special character. So if you use a `-` you can't also use a `_` but you can use another `-`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([\(\)-_,\.\$])(?:\1*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$|^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` will do your job

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IMZ06n/4)

**Details:**

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([\(\)-_,\.\$])` : match any character until you see first special character, place it in group 1

`(?:\1*[a-zA-Z0-9]*)*$` : match pattern starting with special character of group 1 and after that normal characters, as many as possible, until end of the string

`^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` : for special cases when there is no special character, e.g. `abc`

`\1` is called `back-reference`, it will be the last matched group [link to learn more](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences)

Comment: I found a similar solution after reading the resource that ASDFGerte linked (I didn't know about backreferences). This is it: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9]*([-_().,$])?(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]|\1)*$/`. Thanks for your help @mjrezaee :)